# How to remove row which value were found in group before

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I'm currently working on genomic data which contains chromosome start and end position. I want to identify the genomic region which overlap to another region and collapse them into new genomic region.

Although I can identify which region are overlap by GenomicRanges package but it return me to a data which I need to filter out. What I want is to remove row which data in column B not in  column A

```
data<- read.csv(textConnection(
"index,queryhits, subjecthits
 1, 1,  530,
 2, 2,  545,
 3, 2,  799,
 4, 2,  93,
 5, 3,  415,
 6, 4,  745,
 7, 545,799,
 8, 545,93,
 9, 545,415,
 10, 545,745,
 "))
```

The value in subjecthit column should not in queryhit column. For example, in row number 2, queryhit column equal to 2 and subjecthits column equal to 545. It means that 545 is grouped with number 2.

However, a value in queryhit is can be 545 that I don't want to count again that why I want to remove row contain 545 value in queryhits column

The expected output is

```
    index queryhits  subjecthits
     1 1    530
     2 2    545
     3 2    799
     4 2    93
     5 3    415
     6 4    745
```

My real data is about 20000 row so I want a unique number in both queryhit and subjecthits column.

Thank you for any help or suggestion

Answer (score 1):

We could use `%in%` to create a logical index, negate (`!`) and subset the rows of 'data'

```
data[!data$index %in% data$queryhits,]
#   index queryhits subjecthits
# 1     1       530          NA
# 2     2       545          NA
# 3     2       799          NA
# 4     2        93          NA
# 5     3       415          NA
# 6     4       745          NA
```